# Intellij abnormal build process termination

Tags: java, intellij-idea

some wrong happens to my unit test

> Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
> /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java -Xmx700m 
> -Djava.awt.headless=true 
> -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" 
> -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true 
> -Dcompile.parallel=true 
> -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true 
> -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
> -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=9159152397168206635 
> -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
> -Djps.file.types.component.name=FileTypeManager -Duser.language=zh
>  -Duser.country=CN 
> -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2017.1 
> -Didea.home.path=/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39 
> -Didea.config.path=/home/chengtong/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config 
> -Didea.plugins.path=/home/chengtong/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins 
> -Djps.log.dir=/home/chengtong/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/log/build-log 
> -Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/jre64 
> -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=1.8.0_112-release -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true 
> -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/chengtong/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/compile-server/afbp-full_9c7b9e/temp 
> -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.experimental=true 
> -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled 
> -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/tmp/kotlin-idea-8238456638674147489-is-running\" -classpath /media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131/lib/tools.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher /media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/jdom.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/annotations.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/util.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/jps-builders-6.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/protobuf-2.5.0.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/asm-all.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/oromatcher.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/jna-platform.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/log4j.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/openapi.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/jna.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/jps-model.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/trove4j.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/resources_en.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/idea_rt.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/javac2.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/jps-builders.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/snappy-in-java-0.5.1.jar::/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-core-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-ncurses5-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-logging-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/reflectasm-1.07.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-i386-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-amd64-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-ncurses6-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-amd64-libcpp-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-groovy-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/kryo-2.22.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-amd64-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-version-info-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-native-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-ncurses5-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-ncurses6-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/jansi-1.14.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-process-services-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-cli-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-amd64-libstdcpp-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-i386-libcpp-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-i386-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-resources-3.3.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-i386-libstdcpp-0.12.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/gson-2.5.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/maven/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/maven/lib/aether-1.1.0-all.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/maven/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9-all.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/maven/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/aspectj/lib/aspectj-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/flex/lib/flex-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/flex/lib/flex-shared.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jps/jpa-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/webSphereIntegration/lib/jps/webSphere-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/jps/weblogic-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-gradle-jps.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/repository.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/sdklib.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/common.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 34137 6e1570e8-8b38-43ef-a9e9-5250076fbfbb /home/chengtong/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/compile-server Build process started. Classpath: /media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131/lib/tools.jar:/media/chengtong/working/idea-IU-171.4249.39/lib/optimizedFileManager.jarSLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementationSLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:34137; reason: 拒绝连接: /127.0.0.1:34137 io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: 拒绝连接: /127.0.0.1:34137 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:352) at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:612) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438) at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: 拒绝连接 ... 15 moreExiting.

i've solved it by disable my computer firewall ,but it take place again. 
and it never happens when i use windows 10 operate system, now my computer os is Ubuntu16.04.

> ***java version "1.8.0_131"
>
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
>
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)***
>
>   
>   
>   ***Intellij idea version:
> IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2 Build #IU-171.4249.39, built on April 25, 2017 Licensed to chengtong***

Comment: Please format the question using [preformatted code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). It's hard to read the log without proper line termination.

Comment: Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171567.